# Override light/dark mode launch screen on iOS13

Tags: ios13, launch-screen

I only need the light mode on my current app. So I have override the interface style with `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light` but launch screen can not be programmatically modified.

How could I override the launch screen interface style of a launch screen on iOS13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your launch screen, only use non-dymanic colors. For example, use "black" instead of "label" or "Default". Use `white` instead of "systemBackground" or "Default".